# Can pyenv coexist with standard Python 3 install?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, qgis, pyenv

I use `pyenv` to manage Python versions in `Mac OSX High Sierra`, works fine. A new version of an important piece of software for me, `QGIS v3`, requires that `Python 3.6` exist on the system but looks for it only in `/Library/Frameworks`, which pyenv doesn't use. So the install fails.

My question is, will it blow up my Python environment installing Python outside of `pyenv`, with the [Python.org](https://www.python.org/) installer?

Seems risky to try and maybe someone knows...

Comment: Look for documentation on how to install python3 while using python2. It should not mess with environments since the environments idea is to isolate code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add an additional standard installation of Python 3.6.x just to run the QGIS 3 installer. This worked for me (adapt version number):

1. uninstall previously installed Python 3.6.x

   ```
   pyenv uninstall 3.6.8
   ```
2. reinstall with framework

   ```
   env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.6.8
   ```
3. create a symlink

   ```
   sudo ln -s $(pyenv root)/versions/3.6.8/Python.framework /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I do use pyenv at the system level and virtualenv for all development work. The question was specific to QGIS 3, which looks for Python 3.6 in a specific location on the filesystem, under Library/Frameworks and apparently ignores the environment.  Bottom line: a 'standard' install of a Python 3 pkg from the Python site did the trick.